# Вывод Sql запроса в Echo

Tags: php, sql

как вывести sql запрос с Where,через echo в php ?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201929/php-echo-result-of-mysql-select-query) или [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300582/display-sql-query-results-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю, речь о выводе результата этого запроса?

Если так, то нужно выполнить запрос, и результат загнать в массив.

В PHP для вывода массивов используется команда print_r(массив);

Вот полностью готовое решение задачи вывести данные на страницу:

```
<?php
    //подключаемся к mysql
    $link = mysqli_connect("IPсервера", "логин", "пароль", "бд", "порт");

    //выполняем запрос
    $query = "select * from `таблица` where условие";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    //прогоняем через цикл, заполняя массив данными
    while ($element = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $element;
    }

    //выводим массив
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Если это решение Вас не устраивает, и по каким то техническим причинам нужен вывод ИМЕННО ЧЕРЕЗ echo - напишите в комментарий, напишу простенькую программу состоящую из двух циклов для решения этой задачи (*это займёт подольше времени, поэтому пока предлагаю более быстрое решение*)